# Webpack выдает ошибки при сборке проекта, когда пытаюсь подключить файлы Pug

Tags: webpack, pug

```
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing\src\index.pug' in 'C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing'
  ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing\src\index.pug' in 'C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing'  
      at C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:2011:28
      at C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:795:13
      at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:10:1)
      at C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:275:22
      at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
      at C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:431:22
      at C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:124:11
      at C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:667:25
      at C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:852:8
      at C:\Users\sonic\Desktop\landing\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:972:5

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack 5.64.1 compiled with 2 errors in 2602 ms
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! landing@1.0.0 build: `set NODE_ENV=production&&webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the landing@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sonic\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-18T06_16_45_496Z-debug.log
```

index.pug

```
include pug/libs/_libs

doctype html
html(lang='ru')
include pug/_head
  body
    .container
      h1 Hello from Webpack!
      h2.container__subtitle
        | Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum nam, voluptates ad, accusantium modi sunt, earum harum rerum vero obcaecati dolore consequatur! Libero, amet impedit aspernatur ipsam dolorem ipsum architecto!
      +image("box")
```

_head.pug

```
head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge')
    meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
    title Document
```

_image.pug

```
img(src=require(`./src/images/${name}.png`) alt=name)
```

_libs.pug

```
include _image
```

Скриншот структуры проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

let mode = "development";
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  mode = "production";
}
console.log(mode + " mode");

module.exports = {
  mode: mode,
  output: {
    assetModuleFilename: "assets/[hash][ext][query]",
    clean: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].[contenthash].css"
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.pug"
  })],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: "html-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          (mode === "development") ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [
                  [
                    "postcss-preset-env",
                    {
                      // Options
                    },
                  ],
                ],
              },
            },
          },
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource"
      },
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loader: "pug-loader",
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

```
  - Compilation.js:2011
    [landing]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:2011:28

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:795
    [landing]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:795:13


  - NormalModuleFactory.js:275
    [landing]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:275:22


  - NormalModuleFactory.js:431
    [landing]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:431:22

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:124
    [landing]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:124:11

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:667
    [landing]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:667:25

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:852
    [landing]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:852:8

  - NormalModuleFactory.js:972
    [landing]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:972:5

  - child-compiler.js:169
    [landing]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-compiler.js:169:18

  - Compiler.js:559
    [landing]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:559:11

  - Compiler.js:1129
    [landing]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1129:17


  - Hook.js:18 Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync]
    [landing]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:18:14

  - Compiler.js:1125
    [landing]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1125:33

  - Compilation.js:2782 finalCallback
    [landing]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:2782:11

  - Compilation.js:3087
    [landing]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:3087:11


  - Hook.js:18 Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync]
    [landing]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:18:14
```

Comment: Логи из текстового файла который создал npm и дал ссылку в консоль - в студию пожалуйста

Comment: Как достать эти логи?

Comment: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sonic\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-18T06_16_45_496Z-debug.log

Comment: Случайно не подскажете, как подключить в Pug, normalize.css,установленный при помощи npm install normalize.css? Какая нужна команда?

Answer (score 0):

1 ошибка заключалась в том, что index.pug лежал вне папки src.
2 ошибка — была пропущена строчка в миксине изображения, надо бвло написать так:

```
mixin image(name)
  img(src=require(`../src/images/${name}.jpg`) alt=name)
```